# Converting char integer representations to binary

Tags: c, assembly, binary

I have a char array composed of elements 5 3. The array is used to represent number 53. What should be the approach to convert this number of three chars to its binary equivalent? I am implementing this in C, later on it will need to be rewritten in assembly. The solution I seek should be purely low stuff work without any helper libraries.

I am basically stuck with an idea to convert separately 5 and 4 (via mapping 5 and 4 to their ascii equivalents). Yet the idea would not work for sure. I have another idea to convert char '5' to int 5 by right shifting the byte by 4. Same with 4. Then multiply 5 by 10 and add 4, and then use division by two algorithm to find remainder and compose the binary number.

Comment: What have you done yourself? SO is no "do my homework" site.

Comment: Sorry for not providing any information. I am basically stuck with an idea to convert separately 5 and 4 (via mapping 5 and 4 to their ascii equivalents). Yet the idea would not work for sure.

I have an idea to convert char '5' to int 5 by right shifting the byte by 4. Same with 4. Then multiply 5 by 10 and add 4, and then use division by two algorithm to find remainder and compose the binary number

Comment: If you're not sure whether your idea would work, why not try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C:

```
int asciToInteger(char *c)
{
    int result = 0;
    while (*c)
    {
        result *= 10;
        result += (*c - '0');
        c++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Assumes input is valid.

You can get a head start on the assembly language version by compiling with certain switches which will output as ... assembly language! For example in GNU C: `gcc -S -c ascii2int.c`.

Comment: Thank you, sir! That's a neat algorithm! Correct if I am wrong, but ascii numbers only differ by first four bits? 

I will surely use gcc option to translate the code into assembler instruction because the main project has to be in assembler. I just wanted to implement the logic in C so it would be easier to complete the program :)!

Comment: @Lukas Valatka There is nothing ASCII` about this answer.  It works independent of the `char` encoding.

Comment: Yes, in ASCII, UTF, EBCDIC and other coding systems the digits are contiguous and differ by the lowest nybble.